# Debezium Kafka Connector restart not working

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, cdc

I am doing a database upgrade from postgres 12 to 13. I have connectors kafka connectors running for cdc.
Before upgrading i paused my workers, then shutdown my connector service. Then i did below steps. When i shut down my worker my connector configuration was set to `snapshot.mode = never`. Then i performed below steps

1. Delete replication slots from database
2. Delete publications
3. Upgrade the database
4. Create the publication again
5. Create the replication slot
6. Scale up the connector instance
7. Resume the workers

But when i did all the steps, i couldnt see any data being captured by the connectors. The offset also didnt grow.

How can i solve this issue?